# How is an app started from android framework

Tags: android

I am working on a proof-of-concept and I would like to start an app from a class in the android framework source code (/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java)

I tried using code below:

```
Context context = new Context(); //This is not right
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
am.startActivity(context, intent, null);
```

Since I do not have  or do not not know how to get a reference to the Context object, code above does not work.

Any suggestions on how to best to start an app from a class in the android framework?

Comment: You mean you're editing an android class?  You know you'll have to deploy this custom android framework onto the device you're using right?  I believe that means making a custom ROM and flashing it.  Putting aside why you would want to do that, you may not have access to a context from wherever you're writing this code.  You might be able to return an application instance from a static method in an `Application` subclass.  This sounds like a terrible hack though.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, I am editing android class (SQLiteDatabase.java). I know I ve to deploy this custom android framework onto my on device (I'm using Nexus 5).

All that I want to do in my proof-of-concept, is to start an app from this class.